# Server-side Listener in ServiceImpl classes that fires every time an RPC call is made

Tags: gwt, servlets, listener, gwt-rpc

I need to validate if a session is active every time a call from a service method is made using RPC mechanism. Is there a way I could do it once per `RemoteServiceServlet` subclass?, like using some Listener Interface that gets triggered once a method is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a servlet filter that can validate your sesssion before it gets to your servlet.

Check the example here in the question.
[Unable to access session data in servlet filter on app engine dev server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837152/unable-to-access-session-data-in-servlet-filter-on-app-engine-dev-server)

Here's a more thorough example
http://brendangraetz.wordpress.com/2010/06/17/use-servlet-filters-for-user-authentication/

You can add the servlet filter to as many services as you need by adding more filter-mapping stanzas.

```
<!-- Example servlet loaded into servlet container -->
<filter>
   <description>Requires user to log in as a member</description>
    <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>some.package.SecurityFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/com.example.foo.Foo/myService</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<servlet>
  <servlet-name>myServiceImpl</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
    com.example.foo.server.MyServiceImpl
  </servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myServiceImpl</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/com.example.foo.Foo/myService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if I'm using the GWT-RPC mechanism?

Comment: Nope, you can use it with gwt-rpc or request factory. I added an example of the web.xml for a better view of the configuration

Comment: Is there any way that I can send a customized error or alert message to the client? Because in that example it shows `resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);` and that's just a generic message. I want to be more specific with what I'm going to say to the user.

Comment: Haven't had to do this but a couple of suggestions. 1 you can try throwing your own custom exception out of the filter with your custom message. In this case you would extend ServletException and throw this back to the client. The second thing you can try is to use the printwriter to send a message along with the error code. The sendError is simply setting the error code to be 401 but you have the ability to add a text response using the resp.getWriter(). I don't know how the gwt rpc mechanism will parse the message when sending to your AsyncCallback though. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

For those using [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/), I like to use [Guice method interception](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AOP) for that, so I have some custom annotation like:

```
@Override
@Authenticated
public void someRPCCall(...) {
}
```

so, I have several custom annotations that I use depending on the call:

```
@Override
@Authenticated
@Authorizated(accessRolRequired = AccessRol.Editor)
@Transactional
@LogThis
public Boolean someEditorMethod(...)
```

and intercept these calls to make several checks.